# Angularjs tabs does not working in ie8

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive

I am using

```
active="$state.includes()"
```

for tab and it's working well except that I get this error:

```
Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression '$state.includes()' used with directive 'tab' is non-assignable!
```

What is causing this error to happen?

Comment: Which version of AngularJS are you using ? AngularJS 1.3 and higher have dropped support for IE8. AngularJS 1.2 remains IE8 compatible.

Comment: which version of jquery you are using..jquery 2.0 + removed the compatibility with ie8

Comment: I am using Angularjs version 1.2.28